# RestClient Request canceled due to configured Timeout 100 seconds, but I modified it

Tags: httpclient, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient, rest-client

I have below sniped code, until yesterday it worked perfectly, but in this morning I found out in logs following error response:
`response.ErrorException = {"The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing."}`  Does anyone know why in the error is mentioned timeout of 100 seconds while I have another timeout set when I create the `var request = new RestRequest()`?

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.Options.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);
var request = new RestRequest("api/hello", Method.Get) { Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300000).TotalMilliseconds };
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

I forgot to mention, I use RestClient 108.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The `RestClient` has two objects, `Options` and`Options<>`, and I used `Options<>` that has a property `MaxTimeout`. So I increased that one and it works perfectly again.